# Java audio playing solution?

Tags: java, swing

How to use the buttons to play audio with siwng, some example please ?

I'm using a button ok, it plays the song, but when i click the button it just can't get clicked again until the song ends .Any ideas, how to make that works ?Wheni click button to start the audio, and how to do to let me click the button again, until it ends the audio ?

Comment: What you wanna do by clicking the button again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is good example at http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2173111/Java-Sound-Playing-Back-Audio-Files-using-Java.htm and it works fine. The audio gets stopped.

**Update**

I found this interesting link, maybe it helps:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/faq/mp3/mp3.html

Comment: But want to ask you something, im running mp3 file, and im using a javazoom library. How to play mp3 like that insted of au ?

Comment: Sorry it toke so long to answer, i went away this morning. I found some library that maybe can help you http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/faq/mp3/mp3.html

Comment: I did not check sfrj's links, but presume they use Java Sound. In that case, you can simply add the `mp3plugin.jar` of JMF to the run-time class-path of the application - to add MP3 support. No 'javazoom' required.

Answer (score 0):

start a new thread on button click and play the sound there, it will work fine. If you try to play it there, the UI will stuck and you will have issues.